# rake aborted after rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I was having issues migrating databases with mysql and decided to blow the whole thing out of the water and use postgres. I have it installed correctly along with the databases but now I'm getting the same errors I along the lines of when I was using mysql.

```
$ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
/Users/beach180/rails_projects/app/db/migrate/20120114221528_create_users.rb:6: syntax          error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
  t.string "email" :default => "", :null => false
```

This is the rb file

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string "first_name", :limit => 25
      t.string "last_name", :limit => 50
      t.string "email" :default => "", :null => false
      t.string "password", :limit => 40
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

Got any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a comma after the string "email".

```
t.string "email", :default => "", :null => false
                 ^ comma
```

Comment: yep, that was it. About to create another ticket for a different error. Thx Dave :)